# How many triangles which have no sides in common can be formed in n vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are n vertices in the plane. Find the maximal number of triangles which have no same side in common with each other by connecting these vertices. In other words, find the maximal number of triangles which can share vertices but cannot share edges in one n-vertex complete graph.

For example, 4-vertex complete gragh can find 1 triangles with different sides at most. There are some I have comfirmed: A(3)=1, A(4)=1, A(5)=2, A(6)=4, A(7)=7, A(8)=8, A(9)=12, A(10)=13.

The reason why I'm sure these are right is that the upper bound of A(n) is $\lfloor \frac{n\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}{3}\rfloor $. Each vertex can be joined with n-1 edges at most and each vertex in a triangle has two sides. So $n*\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$ means the possible number of sides of triangles. Each triangle has 3 sides. This is how the upper bound $\lfloor \frac{n\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}{3}\rfloor $ formed.

The numbers I listed above all reach the bound except A(5). But A(5)=2 is obvious. I have also tried n=11 but only found 17 triangles, 1 less than the bound. So I'm not sure A(11)?=17.

These are the attampts I have done in this problem. I really cannot find the exact expression for A(n).

Comment: The OEIS sequence [A001839](https://oeis.org/A001839) is what you're looking for. One of the comments for that sequence is `Maximal number of edge-disjoint K_3's in a K_n`. From the page, the formula is stated to be $$A(n) = \begin{cases} \lfloor{(n/3)*\lfloor{(n-1)/2\rfloor}}\rfloor-1 & \text { if } n \equiv 5 \pmod 6 \\ \lfloor{(n/3)*\lfloor{(n-1)/2\rfloor}\rfloor} & \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh, that's really what I want. But I still don't know how to prove it.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81414/how-many-edge-disjoint-cycles-of-length-3-are-in-the-complete-graph